# YouTube automation with selenium and python, problem in selecting from the searched video

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webautomation

Currently I am working on automation of Youtube with Python and Selenium, after searching on Youtube.
I want to select from the searched video per user demands i.e first video, the second or third video, etc.
But I tried almost all selectors, they have the same attributes, they play the first video. So if you have any solution then reply.
Thanks in advance!
The diagram is attached below:)
CODE:

```py
select_video1=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="video-title"]/yt-formatted-string')
select_video1.click()
```

The diagram:

[image: Image is here]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. We'll need some more information to diagnose this issue. Can you include

1. The full code from your python selenium script
2. The image is not helpful. Please provide the HTML for the page, or at least a link to the page under test.
3. Share the full text of the error you are experiencing. Is it simply like `element not found`?

Comment: there is no error, but I wanna play from the searched video as shown in the diagram, but it plays only the first video, how could I play the second or third video?

Comment: Yes, include at least html code of the page you are looking at. IN worst case - a link to it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=decorater

Comment: how could I play the second or third video with selenium in python ? after opening that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work:

```
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=decorater")

video_number = 2

driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//a[@id='video-title'])[{video_number}]").click()
```

This uses [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) so you can make the value dynamic. Just change `video_number` to whichever video you want to play in the list

Comment: thanx,,,it wokred